# Data from POST request not showing in Postman - using MongoDB, full stack ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, postman

I am following a full-stack reactjs Linkedin Learning tutorial by Shaun Wassell. I am building the backend using react and mongodb.

The application includes comments, which requires a POST request. Below is the backend code on server.js

```
app.post ('/api/articles/:name/comments',async(req, res) => {
const {name} = req.params; 
const {postedBy, text} = req.body;
console.log(req.body);
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'); 
await client.connect(); 

const db = client.db('react-blog-db'); 
await db.collection('articles').updateOne({name}, {
    $push: {comments: {postedBy, text}},
})

const article = await db.collection('articles').findOne({name}); 
if (article){
    article.comments.push({postedBy, text}); 
    res.send(article.comments); 
}else{
    res.send(`That article doesn\'t exist!`); 
}
});
```

When I go to Postman and put in any information required, I get a syntax error: "Syntax error: expected name, got string 'postedBy'". Additionally, all of the data in the body is null. The request is 200 OK.
[image]

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: (*I'm a bit sleepy, I might missed something*) Why have you selected "GraphQL" body type, were you not supposed to select "raw -> JSON"? What happens when you send JSON data?